# What type of cheesecake is the most common in southern US SuperMarkets?

Tags: cheesecake

I know there are dozens of types of cheesecake. But I have noticed supermarkets seem to all be making the same type of cake. It has a firm white creamcheese texture that is never tart.

What type of cheesecake is normally found in supermarkets?
The ingredients include (heavy) cream

Comment: This strikes me as being impossible to answer accurately without an extensive international research study.

Comment: I'll remove my question, if nobody knows what I am talking about

Comment: I think the type of cheesecake that Gabriel is describing is fairly specific: it's that generic stuff, not too fluffy, probably no flavor besides vanilla. I don't know if it has a name, but I think it's a reasonable question.

Comment: My answer isn't very specific but might help point people who know more about cheesecake in the right direction.

Comment: I think Elendil's point was that unless you expect us to read your mind and know what scope you intend (e.g. major supermarkets in Helsinki) we have to go on the only scope you've provided, which appears to be all supermarkets in the world. Why don't you buy one and add its ingredients and a photo of a cross-section?

Comment: Fair enough. I will update this post when I get the information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google search for various grocery store cheesecakes reveals:

- http://www.gianteagle.com/entertain/entertaining-guide/dazzling-desserts (Scroll down a little)
- http://www.grocerycouponnetwork.com/images/food-products/Safeway_Select_New_York_Cheesecake.jpg
- http://s3-media2.ak.yelpcdn.com/bphoto/wN7AQw4j1DrckCZWxyMgYw/l.jpg
- http://images.mysupermarket.co.uk/ProductsDetailed/77/177077.jpg
- http://newyork.seriouseats.com/images/20091016cheesecake-sleebox.jpg

Is that what is meant? If so, it appears to be a fairly generic baked New York style cheesecake. Wiki says frozen ones often include sour cream instead of heavy cream, so they'll freeze better.

Comment: This is what I was asking about. Thank you. Sorry for the vagueness.

Answer (score 2):

If it's just based on cream cheese and eggs, it's just a generic cheesecake, for which I don't think there's a name besides simply "cheesecake". (Call it "basic" or "plain" for emphasis if you like.) I believe I've seen plenty of this in stores.

If the ingredients include (heavy) cream, then it's a New York-style cheesecake. It's still a very basic one.